# How JSON web token works in Spring boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, jwt

I want to write REST service and I choose JWT for securing this rest service.
I declare 1 min for token, afterwards what I must do?
I must refresh token or something else?

If I must refresh token, user can call service's method with this token?

**Token code**

```
package com.example.demo.config;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
import io.jsonwebtoken.Claims;
import io.jsonwebtoken.Jwts;
import io.jsonwebtoken.SignatureAlgorithm;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class TokenAuthenticationService {

    //field of conf
    static final long EXPIRATIONTIME = 60_000; // 1 min
    static final String SECRET = "msg";
    static final String TOKEN_PREFIX = "Bearer";
    static final String HEADER_STRING = "Authorization";

    //generate token
    public static void addAuthentication(HttpServletResponse res, Authentication auth) {
        String concattedRoles = "";
        for (GrantedAuthority ga : auth.getAuthorities()) {
            if (!"".equals(concattedRoles))
                 concattedRoles += "," + ga.getAuthority();
             else
                 concattedRoles += ga.getAuthority();
        }
        String JWT = Jwts.builder().setSubject(auth.getName()).claim("roles", concattedRoles)
                .setExpiration(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + EXPIRATIONTIME))
                .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS512, SECRET).compact();
        res.addHeader(HEADER_STRING, TOKEN_PREFIX + " " + JWT);
    }

    //get token from request header.
    public static Authentication getAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request) {
        try {
            System.out.println("(Authentication getAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request)");
            String token = request.getHeader(HEADER_STRING);
            System.out.println("token=>"+token);
            if (token != null) {
                Claims claims = Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(SECRET).parseClaimsJws(token.replace(TOKEN_PREFIX, "")).getBody();
                String user = claims.getSubject();
                String roles = (String) claims.get("roles");

                if(claims.getExpiration().before(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis())))
                    throw new Exception(); //Here trow exception.
                List<String> roleList = Arrays.asList(roles.split("\\s*,\\s*"));
                List<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuths = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
                for (int i = 0; i < roleList.size(); i++) {
                    System.out.println(roleList.get(i));
                    SimpleGrantedAuthority abv = new SimpleGrantedAuthority(roleList.get(i));
                    grantedAuths.add(abv);
                }
                System.out.println(grantedAuths);
                return user != null ? new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user, null, grantedAuths) : null;
            }
            return null;
        }catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println(e);
            return null;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Maybe try to refresh user's current token after each request and send it back?

Comment: If I refresh user's current token, why I must send to back?
User can continue call my service with first token?
If yes, how user will get new token?

Comment: Well idk how this works with headers, but with cookies it works well. When user makes request, you check his JWT-cookie. If it's ok, after request you just put another JWT cookie with the same name, but with modified expiration time. As the result user will have updated JWT in his cookie.

Comment: User won't use browser.
I thinked as below.

At first user will send request with user data(username,password) to my htt://blablba/v1.0/login then I will send token for this user.
Second or another time user call methods of my service via this token.

You sayed refresh token.
That time user must get new token for different request.
This is normal way?

Comment: The preview example I check token expired time, If token expired then I throw exception and User will get 403 "Access Denied".
But I can't know this is normal way or not?

Answer (score 0):

How we implemented is -

1. First time user logs in we send them a token and a refresh token.
2. Client side then uses the 'token' in the header to make further API calls.
3. At client side, we maintain e countdown of 15 minutes (which is lesser than the expiry time of the main token), after which from the client side we send a request to the server with both token and refresh token.
4. After getting a valid refresh token along with the main token, the server sends back a new token with increased exipiry time.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Basically `refresh_token` is used for giving back a valid `access_token` to the user upon request. And `refresh_tokens` are usually long-lived rather than short-lived.

Personally, my design for securing a RESTful API is just to let them request the `access_token` to my endpoint i.e `https://api.example.com/oauth/token` **every time**, I don't provide a `refresh_token` because the idea for me is just to let them in into the resource, nothing else. And usually, the requesting resource will not be staying for so long on a particular session. For the other concerns of the server getting too many requests on the same user/session, you can implement a `rate-limiting` to your servers or token endpoint.

I based my API security implementations on [PayPal](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/overview/#get-an-access-token) and [JHipster](https://www.jhipster.tech/security/#jwt). They do not provide `refresh_tokens` to their respective RESTful API implementations, because in the end, `refresh_tokens` are optional to be used, and it's just a matter of what you want to achieve upon securing your RESTful endpoints.

For more information about `refresh_token` you can these links:
[When to use JWT Tokens](https://auth0.com/blog/refresh-tokens-what-are-they-and-when-to-use-them/) and [Understanding refresh tokens](https://auth0.com/learn/refresh-tokens/).